# Android: How to leave the softkeyboard visible after pressing the button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a screen with edittext and one button.
Edittext has properties

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusedByDefault="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Button has the same properties with *false* values.
On pressing the button there is a change edittext gravity. The edittext does not lose focus when button clicked. But keyboard is hidding.

How to make the keyboard not to hide and stay visible in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this *programatically*. Call this when you click `Button`.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

or

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also with a tag like so:

```
 button.setTag(R.id.DONT_HIDE_KEYBOARD, "true");
```

and under values/ids.xml, add:

```
  <item name="DONT_HIDE_KEYBOARD" type="id"/>
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot, under values/ids.xml, add the type i've included in the answer

Answer (score 0):

try following.code,here focus is your EditText.

```
fun closeInput(focus: View?) {
            val inputMethodManager = mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focus?.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
}
```